# Jolt Spec to remove null elements from the nested array

Tags: json, jolt

Please help in removing nested null elements at root level and inside the options array and also in understanding why options array has null elements in it.

**Input:**

```json
[
  {
    "autoNumber": false,
    "byteLength": 18,
    "controllerName": null,
    "createable": true,
    "defaultValue": null,
    "label": "Case ID",
    "name": "Id",
    "nillable": false,
    "picklistValues": []
  },
  {
    "autoNumber": false,
    "byteLength": 18,
    "createable": false,
    "label": "Asset ID",
    "name": "AssetId",
    "picklistValues": [],
    "nillable": false,
    "type": "reference"
  },
  {
    "autoNumber": false,
    "byteLength": 765,
    "createable": true,
    "label": "Case Type",
    "length": 255,
    "name": "Select list",
    "nillable": true,
    "picklistValues": [
      {
        "label": "Mechanical",
        "validFor": null,
        "value": "Mechanical"
      },
      {
        "label": "Electrical",
        "validFor": null,
        "value": "Electrical"
      }
    ],
    "type": "picklist"
  }
]
```

**Jolt-Spec:**

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "createable": {
          "true": {
            "@(2,name)": ["[#4].crm_field_identifier", "[#4].target_property"],
            "@(2,nillable)": {
              "true": {
                "#false": "[#6].required"
              },
              "false": {
                "#true": "[#6].required"
              }
            },
            "@(2,picklistValues)": {
              "*": {
                "label": "[#6].options[#2].name",
                "value": "[#6].options[#2].value"
              }
            },
            "@(2,defaultValue)": "[&3].default_value"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

**Current O/P:**

```json
[
  {
    "crm_field_identifier": "Id",
    "target_property": "Id",
    "required": "true",
    "default_value": null
  },
  null,
  {
    "crm_field_identifier": "Select list",
    "target_property": "Select list",
    "required": "false",
    "options": [
      null,
      null,
      {
        "name": "Mechanical",
        "value": "Mechanical"
      },
      {
        "name": "Electrical",
        "value": "Electrical"
      }
    ],
    "default_value": null
  }
]
```

**Required O/P:**

```json
[
  {
    "crm_field_identifier": "Id",
    "target_property": "Id",
    "required": "true",
    "default_value": null
  },
  {
    "crm_field_identifier": "Select list",
    "required": "false",
    "options": [
      {
        "name": "Mechanical",
        "value": "Mechanical"
      },
      {
        "name": "Electrical",
        "value": "Electrical"
      }
    ],
    "default_value": null
  }
]
```

Already checked:

1. Modify spec with recursivelySquashNulls which didn't work
2. Remove spec
3. Existing Stackoverflow questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get rid of square bracket symbols which wrap #-prefixed integers, while decrementing those integers except for the array(namely "options"),

eg. convert **`[#6]`** to **`&5`**, **`[#4]`** to **`&3`**; for `"options"` : **`[#2]`** to **`[&1]`**(*keep square brackets*) such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "createable": {
          "true": {
            "@(2,name)": ["&3.crm_field_identifier", "&3.target_property"],
            "@(2,nillable)": {
              "true": {
                "#false": "&5.required"
              },
              "false": {
                "#true": "&5.required"
              }
            },
            "@(2,picklistValues)": {
              "*": {
                "label": "&5.options[&1].name",
                "value": "&5.options[&1].value"
              }
            },
            "@(2,defaultValue)": "&3.default_value"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // get rid of the integer object keys
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "@": ""
      }
    }
  }
]
```

keep in mind that `#-prefixed` identifier starts counting from **1**, while `&-prefixed` from **0**

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is :

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Barbaros. What is the difference b/w #3 and &2 ? I have been using those interchangeably till now.

Comment: You're welcome @Dharanidhar They're quite similar on the RHS, except there's one integer value difference between them counting per each level ( eg: [#2] nearly equals [&1] ) and using [& ] prones to generate nulls rather than [# ], but in this case the tricky part is not related to them, indeed get rid all of them as they would generate nulls for missing indexed objects(here the one with the key 1). So used the identifiers without brackets.